# Shutting down H2 database; Compact vs Defrag?

Tags: java, h2

In my application, I connect to an H2 database and I've recently being looking into how this database is shutdown.

In my connection string I have set `DEFRAG_ALWAYS=true`, which according to H2 doc

> Each time the database is closed, it is fully defragmented  (SHUTDOWN DEFRAG).

Now I assume that when the JVM is shutting down, the shutdown hook will then shutdown the database and defragment it (as if executing `SHUTDOWN DEFRAG`).

But if I was to execute `SHUTDOWN COMPACT` before exiting the application, whilst having `DEFRAG_ALWAYS=true` applied in the connection string, Which shutdown process would be used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you execute `shutdown` manually, then this has priority over the setting (`defrag_always=true`). So if you execute `shutdown compact`, then this is what is done, and the `defrag` is not done. If you execute `shutdown defrag`, then this is done, no matter what the setting. If you just close the database normally, then the setting `defrag_always` is used.